# jquery validation plugin - resetForm()

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a login form that is getting validated on submit. This login form doesn't initially validate onkeyup events because validation is only called on submit, which is what I want. If I submit the form with invalid field values i.e., blank, errors are correctly generated.

However, when I correct the errors and successfully login and then logout, the login form now generates errors for both fields for onkeyup. I've tried using resetForm(), which corrects the behavior for the username field, but the password field still generates an error for onkeyup. I also tried setting onkeyup: false, then calling resetForm(),  but then I have to change my validation event binding to 'mousedown' instead of 'click', which is causing validation to work incorrectly.

I also tried reset() on the form itself but this doesn't work either. How can I correctly implement resetForm() so that both fields ignore validation for onkeyup events when the user initially comes to the login page, as well as when they logout and return to the login page, without having to reload the page.

```
  init_language(function(){
    var placeholderLabels = $('label[for="userId"], label[for="password"]').not('.error');
    $('html').i18n();
    if($('#sidebar-login fieldset span').length>0) {
       $(placeholderLabels).css({'display':'block'});
    } else {
       $('#userId, #password').placeholder();     
    }  
  });
  $('#input, #password').blur(function(){
    $('html').i18n();
    if($('#sidebar-login fieldset span').length>0) {
       return;
    } else {
       $('#userId, #password').placeholder();  
    }  
  });
  var validator = $("#sidebar-login").validate();
  validator.resetForm();
}

  $('.ajax_button_submit').live('click', function() {
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    var is_submit = true;

    if (form.attr('error') && !form.data('visit')) {
      form.validate({errorLabelContainer: form.attr('error')});
      form.data('visit', 1);
    }

    if (is_submit && form.valid()) {
      var url = form.attr('url') || form.attr('action');
      var type = form.attr('type') || 'json';
      if (type == 'json') {
        var data = JSON.stringify($('[data-submit!=false], #password[realtype!=text]', form).serializeJSON());
      } else {
        var data = $('[data-submit!=false], #password[realtype!=text]', form).serialize();
      }
```

Thanks for any help,

J

Comment: I figure it out. I had to unbind the form with: $('#sidebar-login').data('validator', null);

Comment: You're not using the jQuery Validate plugin so please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.  And since you figured out your problem, please post the answer below so that it helps others.  Otherwise, if you prefer, you could flag your question for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. I had to unbind the form with:$('#sidebar-login').data('validator', null);